# What is the difference between function and object function

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$.action = {
   do : function() {
     return 'im doing';
   }
};



function do() {
  return 'im doing';
}



var action= function() {
   var do = function() {
      return 'im doing'; 
   }

   return {

        init : function () {
          do();
        }
   }
}();
```

Calls :

```
$.actions.do();
do();
action.init();
```

Hola Amigos,

I am newbee..

There are a lot of usage of functions. But what is the difference between them ? What should i use ?

When i use first one, when i use second, when i use third ?

Thanks for advice...

Comment: It depends entirely on what scope you want the function to have. Either is useful for different scenarios, although I'd suggest that you shouldn't really add anything to the `$` namespace.

Comment: The 2nd case is called the Revealing Module Pattern. I would recommend reading into it, and learning other common JS design patterns.

Comment: Thank you very much for unique information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st case is similar to the last case. It's an object that has some methods. The advantage of using the last example, is that you can have "private" variables and functions and you only expose what's necessary trough the returned object.

1st one also can be use for name-spacing. $.module1.do, $.module2.do

2nd case is just a function declaration. Useful when you want for example to write reusable, more general purpose functions.